# Write a program that translates a text to Fake Latin and back

Tags: java, string, reverse

Write a program that translates a text to Fake Latin and back. English is translated to Fake Latin by taking the first letter of every word, moving it to the end of the word and adding ‘ay’ to each word.
As an example, if your program reads from the keyboard the string “The quick brown fox” then it should print on the screen the following text: “Hetay uickqay rownbay oxfay”.
You should also implement the reverse of this, reading "Iay ikelay rogrammingpay" should print on the screen "I like programming".

```
public class fakelatin {    

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     Scanner pig = new Scanner(System.in);
     String word;  original word
     String latin = "";  
     char first;
     boolean cap = false;
     String line;

     System.out.print("enter line to translate: "); //enter the line to translate
     line = pig.nextLine();
    pig = new Scanner(line);

    // loop through all the words in the line
     while (pig.hasNext())  // is there another word?
     {
        word = pig.next();
        first = word.charAt(0);

        if ('A' <= first && first <= 'Z')  // first is capital letter
        {
           first = Character.toLowerCase(first);

           cap = true;
        }
        else
            cap = false;

     // test if first letter is a vowel
        if (first=='a' || first=='e' || first=='i' || first=='o' || first=='u')
           latin = word + "ay";

       else
        {   
           if (cap)
           {
              latin = "" + Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(1));  // char to String conversion
              latin = latin + word.substring(2) + first + "ay";
           }

           else  
              latin = word.substring(1) + first + "ay";


        }



        System.out.print(latin + " ");

     } 

  }
}
```

i have got the output as iay ikelay rogrammingpay as i want it

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fakelatin2 {  


  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     Scanner pig = new Scanner(System.in);
     String word; // original word
     String latin = "";  // pig latin translation, init to empty string
     char first,last;
     boolean cap = false;
     String line;

     System.out.print("enter line to translate: ");
     line = pig.nextLine();
     pig = new Scanner(line);

     // loop through all the words in the line
     while (pig.hasNext())  // is there another word?
     {
        word = pig.next();
        first = word.charAt(0);
        last=word.charAt(word.length()-1);

        if ('A' <= first && first <= 'Z')  // first is capital letter
        {
           first = Character.toLowerCase(first);

           cap = true;
        }
        else
            cap = false;




           latin = word.replaceAll("ay", "");
        if(cap)
        {
            latin = "" + Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(1));
         latin=latin+word.substring(word.length()-1);
        }
        System.out.print(latin + " ");

     } 


  }
}
```

i am getting an output as "i ikel rogrammingp" but not able to get "i like programming"back

Comment: `word.replaceAll("ay", "")` seems dangerous, what if your word is play (laypay)?  It will get mangled, you may want to use `word.replaceAll("ay$", "")` (using a [regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum)) or `word.substring(0, word.length() - 2)`

Comment: it gives output like "I Iikel Iikelrogrammingp"

Comment: You remove all instances of "ay", but never move the last char to the front, you may want `latin = latin.substring(latin.length() - 1) + latin.substring(0, latin.length() - 1);`

Comment: Another issue is that if `cap` is true, `latin = "" + Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(1));` will set `latin` to the first char and erase the rest

Answer (score 0):

To convert back from pig-latin, write out the algorithm:

1. Get the 3rd-from-last letter. That's the original first letter
2. Check if first letter is caps. Convert result from step #1 to upper.
3. Remove the last 3 letters. The original 1st + "ay"
4. Build new word.

Like this:

```
while (pig.hasNext())  // is there another word?
{
    word = pig.next();

    // Step 1.
    // Original first letter of word
    last = word.charAt(word.length() - 3);
    // word.length should always be >= 3, but I guess you should check
    // that and print an error if it's not.

    // Step 2.
    // First char in latin word
    first = word.charAt(0);
    if (Character.isUpperCase(first))  // first is capital letter
    {
        last = Character.toUpperCase(last);
    }

    // Steps 3. and 4.
    String original = last + word.substring(0, word.length() - 3).toLowerCase();

    System.out.print(original + " ");
}
```

Note: I don't see how you can convert back words that start with a vowel. For example: "end" is "enday" in fake-latin. When you convert back, how do you know it's "end" or "den"? (Because "den" in fake-latin is also "enday"). However, the assignment doesn't say anything about words that start with vowels, so you should remove that from your converter. Problem solved.

Comment: You should be consistent, use `Character.isUpperCase(first)` if you're using `Character.toUpperCase(last)`

Comment: @phflack Ok. Updated.